# Передача данных по wifi

Tags: java, android, wifi, raspberry-pi

Нужно организовать общение raspberry Pi по wifi с android приложением.
Каким образом лучше организовать передачу данных по wifi на android?

Answer (score 2):

Решением может быть REST веб сервис.

- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST
- https://habr.com/post/38730/

На RPI устанавливается jre и tomcat.

- https://micro-pi.ru/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-tomcat-8-ubuntu-16-04-armbian/
- http://androidsrc.net/installing-tomcat8-raspberry-pi-3/

Вы пишете на java сервлет, который будет принимать и обрабатывать http запросы и разворачиваете его на tomcat.

- https://habr.com/post/115718/
- https://o7planning.org/ru/11199/java-restful-web-services-tutorial-for-beginners

Под android пишете клиента, который будет отправлять эти запросы.

- http://spring-projects.ru/guides/consuming-rest-android/

Comment: Можно более подробно рассказать про этот метод, пожалуйста

Comment: На RPI устанавливается jre и tomcat. Вы пишете на java сервлет, который будет принимать и обрабатывать http запросы и разворачиваете его на tomcat. Под android пишете клиента, который будет отправлять эти запросы.
https://habr.com/post/115718/
https://o7planning.org/ru/11199/java-restful-web-services-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Пофиксил ответ.